# Show part of image (unknow width and height) in fixed dimensins 60x60

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a image e.g.,

[image]

original dimension of the image is 875 x 583, here I want to show face in seperate div with fixed height,

I know the dimensions for the face

```
bottom:456
left:277
right:599
top:134
```

I want to show this part of the image in fixed div 60x60

How can I do that?

right now I can show only the face part using margins

```
<div class="face-img" style="height: 322px; width: 322px;">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHXcI.png" style="width: 875px; height: 583px; margin: -134px -599px -456px -277px;">
</div>
```

but I have to give width and height as original dimensions which are not fixed.

Sample jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/new513/8vedg370/4/

I have lot of images like this that I want to show with different dimension, so I'm more of interested in dynamic approach to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

horizontal dimension of the face  599 - 277 = 322
final horizontal dimension = 60
horizontal ratio = 322 / 60 = 0.186
final horizontal dimension of the image 875 * 0.186 = 163

vertical dimension of the face  456 - 134 = 322

final vertical dimension = 60

vertical ratio = 322 / 60 = 0.186

final vertical dimension of the image 583 * 0.186 = 108

left position original 277px
same ratio as above 0.186
horizontal position 51px

top position original 134px
same ratio as above 0.186
vertical position 25px

```css
.box {
 width:60px;
 height:60px;
 background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHXcI.png);
 background-size: 163px 108px;
 background-position: -51px -25px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS clipping to achieve the cropping of your image.
You simply wrap the image in a container div and set the clipping attribute to the image, you can use the following code.

The HTML code :

```
  <div class="container">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHXcI.png">
  </div>
```

The CSS code:

```
 .container{
  width : 322px;
  height : 322px;
  position : relative;
  display : block;
 }

.container img{
  position : absolute;
  clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry about that i forgot to enter the code which i used whilst inspecting: change the css clip line to this :  clip: rect(75px,323px,245px,151px);

Comment: Hey how did you come with up those values? Did you do any calculations? I'm looking for dynamic way of doing this as I have other images I need to apply this logic to